# video cards don't work properly ASUS N550 JK

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee, hybrid-graphics

First time i ask for help here, but after a week tryng to solve the problem just reading i decided to write something too:

As title says i have this N550 JK, i installed ubuntu 14.04, bumblebee and the nvidia 331 drivers (i have a 850m inside togheter with the intel), anyway when i enter the `lshw -c display` command it gives me this output:

```
praedo@Drake:~$ sudo lshw -c display
*-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: 3D controller
   product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:36 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

as you can see the nvidia card seems to be UNCLAIMED.

of course this is not the only problem i have, i cannot use my nvidia card in any way, seems bumblebee doesn't recognize even his existance.

anyone able to help?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Why do you have Bumblebee?  What are you trying to accomplish? (meaning: is it OK to remove Bumblebee and do things differently depending on your use case?)

Comment: After breaking my head on my pc for a little more i discovered that i did the things in the wrong way. I thought i needed bumblebee to switch from a video card to another. I solved this removing bumblebee and installing nvidia drivers and the prime switch. Thanks a lot for answering!

Comment: I'll convert that to an answer!

Answer (score 0):

As your use case is to have NVidia drivers available at all times, the easiest thing for you is to remove Bumblebee:

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Just in case, that removed too much, check whether you still have the xorg-edgers PPA in your sources:

```
 grep --recursive --ignore-case xorg-edgers /etc/apt/* 2> /dev/null
```

(should give you more then 0 lines) and install NVidia drivers again:

```
 sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

And you should be good to go again!